# How do I exit a Python program that has a thread running?

Tags: python, multithreading, exit

I'm writing some simple code and I use Pygame for graphics and I  have a thread that draws everything. When I call sys.exit() or just ctrl+c, the main program exits but the thread seems to still be alive. I think I need to shut it down before. How do I do that?

Example:

```
import threading

class Bla(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "I draw here"

Bla().start()

while True:
     if user_wants_to_end:
         sys.exit()
```

And when I do want to exit the program doesn't exit! How do I shut the thread down?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate; you might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python/325528#325528) for some help.

Comment: "Simple code" and "thread" in the same sentence? Tsk, tsk. Don't use multithreading because it seems to be a good idea, use it when you actually need it.

Comment: This program does not exactly show your problem, because it does exit quite quickly.  The problem can be illustrated if you add something like `time.sleep(1000000)` in the `run()` method, though.

Comment: Make `Bla.run()` check a global flag or something that signals it when it's time to quit.

Answer (score 2):

Python programs exit when all non-daemon threads are done.

```
class Bla(threading.Thread):
    daemon = True # Make the thread daemon
    def run(self):
        print "I draw here"
```

Comment: For reference: "The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left." (threading module documentation).

Comment: Isn't there a way to ask a thread to terminate, from the main program, without handling this specifically in the thread code?

Comment: I pretty sure the answer is no. Either you use a process (see muliprocessing) or have explicit checks in your thread code (usually using Events).